# Insert into..select with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I have two tables

Table 1:

```
process  status
 1        completed
 2       completed 
 3       not completed
```

`table 2` ; is a history table that gets its data from table1

```
process status
1       completed
2       completed
3      not completed
```

Next time when the data gets pushed into history table from table 1 i want only that data to be pushed whose status is 'not completed'

Such that my history table looks like below

Table 2 (history table)

```
Process   status
  1       completed
  2       completed
  3       not completed
  3       completed
```

Please help me out with this, I have tried subqueries but it isnt working out for me.

I used this query:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE NOT (status IN (SELECT Status 
                          FROM table2 
                          WHERE status = 'completed'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (process,status)
select process,'completed' as status From table1 where process in
(select distinct process from table2 where status <> 'completed')
```

Comment: Don't recommend `*` in `insert` statement. Then `<>` will be more meaningful when comparing single value

Comment: I need to check the status of records in table2 where status <> completed, and fetch only those records from table1

Comment: So process `3` from `table2` qualifies your condition and you want to insert it to `table2` with status as `complete`?

Comment: Process 3 is incomplete as per table2 , so next time when data gets inserted into table2 from table1, it should only be for process3 as its status is incomplete. I need updates only on those processes whose status is incomplete.

Comment: See the updated answer. Although it doesn't make much sense to me to hardcode the `status` but looks like this is what you need. Please confirm.

Comment: table 1 gets populated by a procedure , so i guess there is no need to hardcode it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to **match some column** in **both** the **Tables**:

```sql
UPDATE _table_name_ 
SET col1 = _alias_table_.col1, ... /* all columns except merge keys and Identity column */
FROM (SELECT * FROM _tmp_table1_ UNION SELECT * FROM _tmp_table2_) _alias_table_
WHERE _table_name_._merge_key_ = _alias_table_._merge_key_ /* could be multiple merge keys */
```

**Example:**

```sql
update orderdetails 
set productname = a.productname 
from (select productid,productname from products) as a 
join orderdetails o 
on o.productid = a.productid 
where a.productid = o.productid;
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAI understood your question, you need updates on status for processes which have changed from incomplete to complete state(assuming that the flow is linear from incomplete to complete) only.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (process,status)
SELECT 
T1.process as process, 
CASE T1.state WHEN 0 THEN 'not completed ' ELSE 'completed' END as status
FROM 
(SELECT process, MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'not completed' THEN 0 WHEN status ='completed' THEN 1 END) state from table1 group by process) T1 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT process, MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'not completed' THEN 0 WHEN status ='completed' THEN 1 END) state from table2 group by process) T2
ON  T1.process=T2.process 
WHERE T2.process is NULL OR T2.state<> T1.state
```

[**SQL demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c383f/2)